# What does the // regex in Perl exactly do?

Tags: regex, perl

In a Perl project I am auditing I come across a lot of code patterns like this:

```perl
my ($first, $second) = split(//, $words, 2);
if ($first =~ //i) {
      # do something
}
```

I'm not sure what is happening here. From what I can tell when executing the program is that it splits `$words` on spaces, but no idea why. Also what is the `if` condition checking?

I saw [The empty pattern //](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#The-empty-pattern-//), but not sure how that applies here as there are no other regexes in the function that contains the above snippet.

Comment: Is that actually what you have?

Answer (score 4):

> *From what I can tell when executing the program is that it splits $words on spaces*

This is incorrect.

`split` treats a match operator as a `qr//` operator, allowing a pre-compiled pattern to be provided, even before `qr//` came into existence.

While the empty pattern normally has a special meaning for the match and substitution operators, it is not the case for a match operator used as a `qr//` operator for `split`. An empty pattern has it's usual meaning of always matching.<sup>[1]</sup>

As such, `split //` causes `split` to split a string into individual characters.

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'say join ":", split(//, "abcd")'
a:b:c:d
```

In your case, the third argument limits `split` to a single cut.

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'say join ":", split(//, "abcd", 2)'
a:bcd
```

So `$first` receives the first character of the string in `$words`, and `$second` receives the remainder of the string.

---

So that leaves `$first =~ //i`.

An empty pattern for the match operator causes the last successfully matched regular expression to used instead.

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'$_ = "foo"; /(.)oo/; /(.)ar/; "moo" =~ //; say $1;'
m
```

It's an obscure feature to begin with, and here it's used after a `split`. This is horrible code. Does matches perform by `split` count? Testing reveals the answer is no.

So we can't tell what `$first =~ //i` does from the code you posted, since it's using the pattern from an earlier unshown match.

---

1. This should make it obvious why:

   ```perl
   "aaaaa" =~ /(?:aaa)/   # Matches 3 chars at pos 0.
   "aaaaa" =~ /(?:aa)/    # Matches 2 chars at pos 0.
   "aaaaa" =~ /(?:a)/     # Matches 1 chars at pos 0.
   "aaaaa" =~ /(?:)/      # Matches 0 chars at pos 0.
   ```

Answer (score 1):

From the [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) docs:

```
However, this:

    print join(':', split(//, 'abc')), "\n";

uses empty string matches as separators to produce the output
"a:b:c"; thus, the empty string may be used to split EXPR into a
list of its component characters.

As a special case for "split", the empty pattern given in match
operator syntax ("//") specifically matches the empty string,
which is contrary to its usual interpretation as the last
successful match.
```

Then, from [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#The-empty-pattern-//) (which you already saw):

```
The empty pattern //

If the PATTERN evaluates to the empty string, the last successfully
matched regular expression is used instead. In this case, only the g
and c flags on the empty pattern are honored; the other flags are
taken from the original pattern. If no match has previously succeeded,
this will (silently) act instead as a genuine empty pattern (which
will always match).
```

The previous regex does not need to be in the same function. Whatever the previous regex was *in time* is the previous regex. That's one of the reasons people shouldn't rely on this sort of thing unless they also control the sequence of events, such as using this immediately after a successfully applied pattern.